# Give a user remote access to Stored Procedures

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, permissions

I have a MySQL Database on a host with ip 192.168.1.1 where I created some stored procedures with my root user. I created another user called foo. I have multiple hosts with 192.168.1.x with connect to the database with DBeaver with the user foo. Now the problem is that the stored procedures were created with root so foo has no access. How can I give foo all the access to the procedures?

It's not working with

```
GRANT SELECT, INSERT,UPDATE,DELETE,EXECUTE ON dbname.*  TO 'foo'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```

Nor

```
GRANT SELECT, INSERT,UPDATE,DELETE,EXECUTE ON dbname.*  TO 'foo'@'%';
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Add `SQL SECURITY DEFINER` stored procedure option. And do not forget to grant SP execution to `foo@%` user(s).

Comment: How do I grant SP execution? I found so many statements but none worked. Can you give me an example how you do it?

Comment: [MySQL 8.0 Reference Manual  /  ...  /  GRANT Statement # Stored Routine Privileges](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/grant.html#grant-routine-privileges)